# What is a bubble from nothing?

Tags: string-theory, vacuum, quantum-gravity, instantons, bubbles

Recently I was reading a collection of lectures on Swampland Conjecture and came across an interesting subtitle about a bubble from nothing.

> A bubble from nothing is a non-perturbative instability that mediates the decay of a vacuum into nothing, that is, the vacuum annihilates itself. This occurs when the compact size collapses to zero size at the bubble wall. Therefore, it is literally a bubble with nothing inside (even with space-time) that appears in a vacuum and begins to expand at the speed of light, leaving nothing behind.

What exactly does "nothing" mean? A state without space-time, but still a state of a physical system? Or "nothing" in the literal sense, that is, the absence of something? What it is from a physical point of view?

Link to article:
https://arxiv.org/abs/2102.01111

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Closed string tachyon condensation can lead to the decay of space-time dimensions. The endpoint of these condensations are what is refered to as the "nothing" state. What this really is is not yet clear. From a string field theory point of view it is a CFT whose perturbative cohomology vanishes, i.e. there are no pertubative states remaining in the theory. Especially there are no spacetime dimensions. But one can still formulate a string field theory around this nothing, the so called vacuum string field theory. And this is still equivalent ( due to background independence) to any other SFT.

The condensation of the tachyon itself starts at a point in spacetime and extends at the speed of light, this is what is now known as a bubble of nothing, first introduced by Witten in the setup of toriodal compactifications.

So in short: There are no perturbative states in "nothing", but non-perturbativ instantons still exist.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But it's still a physical state, isn't it? And the strings in the condensate continue to interact?

Comment: That depends on your definition of state. Usually a physical state is defined as a perturbation of a vacuum state. As there are no such states left, there are no physical states. The condensate is a deformation of a 2d CFT by relevant operators. So these are still states in this theory, although strongly coupled and it is not really understood what this means. If you want to understand this a bit better i would recommand reading the paper https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0506077, although this probably requires a bit of basics of SFT.

Comment: I mean, it's still a physical system. That is, "nothing" does not mean the absence of anything.

Comment: That's not the nothing referred to... (it could ultimately be the same thing, which would be nice).

Comment: Actually it is the same thing. It depends only on the formulation. A closed string tachyon describes an instability of the spacetime. If this is due to a compactification like in Irene's paper on the Cobordism conjecture and in Witten's original work or due to a bulk tachyon does not really matter for the end result. Also, one can describe these systems in a SFT setup or in a first quanized version and use CFT methods like Simeon Hellerman did, in all cases a state without cohomology is the result. ( in some cases one can reach states with remaining perturbative states like 2d type 0 strings)

Comment: @Rohbar: The "bubble of nothing" instability exists independently of string theory, so the relation to closed-string tachyons that you propose is not as obvious as you suggest. I'd anyway be interested in reading about it. (What is the Hellerman paper?)

Comment: You are absolutely right, I assumed a string theory setup. Hellerman did write a whole series of papers about tachyon transitions, this one summarizes the results nicely .https://arxiv.org/pdf/0705.0980.pdf

Comment: Ah excellent glad we're on the same page. Thanks for the reference too!

Answer (score 1):

Actually it's a bubble *of* nothing. This was originally found by [Witten](https://inspirehep.net/literature/10780), and is best explained by Witten. It's an instability of Kaluza-Klein spacetimes, where from the perspective of the lower-dimensional observer, a bubble forms, so that the lower dimensional spacetime is Minkowski minus a bubble of some radius
$$r(t)=\sqrt{R^2+t^2}$$
where $R$ is the radius of the KK circle. As $t$ increases, the spacetime disappears into "nothing".

Comment: Does the entire universe disappear with space-time? That is, "nothing" is the absence of something?

Comment: I don't understand the question.

Comment: What is "nothing"? Is it a physical system in an unknown state, or the absence of any physical system?

Comment: There's no physical system anymore; space ends where the bubble begins. As I say in the answer, the (lower-dimensional) spacetime is Minkowski *sans* the bubble. If go into the bubble, nobody knows what happens to you.

Comment: That is, there is nothing inside the bubble? Spacetime, matter, everything just disappears? Or do we not yet have a theory that would describe what is "inside" the bubble? For example, the complete theory of quantum gravity.

Comment: And what happens to particles, to energy in such a process? Do they disappear too?